# stop interval inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that runs a soccer game clock,
when I click the start button everything is working properly
but I can't stop the clock.

```js
var count;

function gameClock() {

  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
  var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
  var totalSeconds = 0;
  var count = setInterval(function() {
    setTime()
  }, 1000);

  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
}



//Start Stop Game Clock
$(document).on('click', '#f_start', function() {

  $("#half_name").text('FIRST HALF');

  gameClock();
 //     localStorage.setItem('first_half_click', getTime());
 //     localStorage.setItem('half', 1);
})

$(document).on('click', '#f_stop', function() {

  clearInterval(count);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="f_start"> START</button>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="f_stop"> STOP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue likely has to do with scoping.  You technically have two `count` variables, one in the scope of the function, and one outside that scope that's never assigned.  try to remove the `var` when you assign `count` to the interval.

Comment: Please add the rest of the HTML. I made a snippet and commented out the localStorage part sine you are not using it and StackSnippets does not like it

Comment: Voting to close as typo-type - solution is to remove var from `var count = setInterval(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the `count` global variable inside the `gameClock` method which means it's scope is only in that function. change the assignment to use the global `count` variable instead of the useless local variable.

```js
 var count = setInterval(function() {
     setTime()
  }, 1000);

 //to
  count = setInterval(function() {
   setTime()
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: That is a typo-type issue not helping anyone else. Perhaps just vote to close?

Comment: I think it's helpful for beginners struggling with javascript scope

Comment: There will be a million similar ones. No-one will find THIS when they have a scope problem

Comment: And if they do, I posted the solution as a comment

Comment: Thank You For all the replays. it was very helpful!